# Group by id and get all rows corresponds to min value in a column

Tags: python, pandas

**I have a dataset with three columns A,B and C.** 
*

```
A B C 
1 2 3 
1 3 4 
1 4 5 
1 2 6 
2 1 9 
2 9 8 
2 8 2 
2 1 2
```

- 

**I need to get value of A,B,C columns corresponds to min B value grouped by A column.

As you can see I have duplicated values for A{1,2}B and A{2,1}B. If I do this command: 

dataset['A,'B','C'].loc[dataset.groupby('A').B.idxmin()] 

I get only first value of A,B,C for min B. But how can I get all rows?** \

```
Output: 
A B C 
1 2 3 
2 1 9 
Output expected: 
A B C 
1 2 3 
1 2 6 
2 1 9 
2 1 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and compare by column `B` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = dataset[dataset.groupby('A').B.transform('min').eq(dataset['B'])]
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
3  1  2  6
4  2  1  9
7  2  1  2
```